# How to animate my button to a fixed position and animate when scrolling down then animate again when scrolling back up jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

How to animate my button to a fixed position when scrolling down then animate again to to original position when scrolling back up in jquery. The animation happens only one time i want it to happen all the time but the animation only does once

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 200) {
      $('.back').addClass('HomeButtonFloat');
   
     $('.back').animate({bottom:'0px'}, 800);
  
    } 
 
 else  {
     $('.back').removeClass('HomeButtonFloat');
      
        
     
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.back{
    background-image: url('http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/466581761641871614/files/AppWidgets/Widgets/Initial2.1.jpg');
    background-size: 150px 150px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-position:center center;
   width:180px;
   height:180px;
   border-radius:15px;
   border:solid black 5px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   margin-top:30px;
   box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 5px red;
  
  
}


.HomeButtonFloat {
    background-image: url('http://www.weebly.com/editor/uploads/1/1/3/4/11341626/custom_themes/466581761641871614/files/AppWidgets/Widgets/Initial2.1.jpg');
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
    position:fixed;

 left:10px;
 
 
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="height:1550px;">
<div class="back"> 
 <a href="Chicago.html">
</a>
</div> 



</body>
```

Comment: also the button becomes transparent as u start scrolling either up or down and goes back to its normal opacity but if un active the opacity takes affect

Comment: Try this:apply with `transition:all 0.8s linear ` in your css

Comment: i am still experimenting with transition and animation